# Owebia Shipping selected country shipping list

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, countries

Owebia Shipping implement in my store. how i disable country which i not want to shipped item. there are no any selection for specific country selected list. i want to ship item only in 50 country , other country not select from shipping step.
can you please give me answer ASAP.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky then the extension uses the standard Magento way of selecting countries. For standard shipping methods you can specify if the method can be used for "All Allowed Countries" or "Specific Countries".

So you have two options.

1. You can either specify which are the allowed countries under `System->Config->General->Countries Options`,
2. Or you specify the Specific countries that this one shipping method is allowed for.